# How do I get the vertical offset of a React Native TextInput in the onFocus event?

Tags: react-native, measure, onfocus, react-native-textinput

I want to get the vertical offset of a React Native TextInput in the onFocus event for that element. I have the following code in a `TextInputCustom` component I created:

```
let textInput;

<TextInput
    onFocus={(evt) => {
        textInput.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
            console.log('textInput.measure', x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
        });
    }}
    ref={(ref) => textInput = ref}
/>
```

This "works", in that I can see a value for `pageY`, but the problem is that when I add multiple `TextInputCustom` components to a screen, it seems to report out the same `pageY` value for all of them, as if the `ref` is shared by all of them or something like that. (Honestly, I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm sure that they're all reporting out the same `pageY` value, even though they're all clearly at differing vertical offsets.)

I was thinking about changing `textInput.measure` to `evt.target.measure`, but `evt.target` seems to be an element ID and not an actual element. I read some stuff on SO about using `ReactNativeComponentTree` to get the actual element from the element ID, but I can't seem to properly require/import it.

At this point I'm stuck, and looking for any advice on how to properly get the vertical offset of a `TextInput` element when it's focused on, even when there are multiple `TextInput` elements on a given screen. Thank you.

---

**Edit**: Max, as per your comments, I modified my functional component as follows:

```
const TextInputCustom = (props) => {
    const textInputElem = useRef(null);

    <TextInput
        onFocus={(evt) => {
            textInputElem.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
                console.log('textInput.measure', x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
            });
        }}
        ref={textInputElem}
    />
};
```

I've noticed that the `onFocus` event fires for the first `TextInputCustom` component on the screen, but none of the others. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: you have many textinputs so you need just as many refs. You only have 1, textInput, which is getting overwritten every render

Comment: Yeah, that's the feeling I'm getting, but what is confusing is that the code above is in its own component, so I would think that each instance of the component would have its own local `textInput` variable that would store the ref for just that instance. All the same, is there any good way around this issue or way to use `evt.target` to get just the input that was focused on? Thank you.

Comment: if every component has its own ref then it should be fine. It's hard to tell what's wrong without entire example, e.g. this line `let textInput;` is it outside of component somewhere in the file? If yes then all instances will share one variable and owerwrite each other. Is it inside render method? then you are better off with class property. Is it inside of a functional component? then you should be using useRef

Comment: Max, I modified my question as per your comments. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Max, please ignore my last comment. It actually works. I wasn't properly testing things. Thank you so much for your advice. Thanks.